# Delete rows where a row.cell has a specific string with VBA

Tags: string, excel, delete-row, vba

I have an Excel file with 390 rows. On the fifth column there are only two strings. It is either "YES" or "NO". So, I am trying to delete the rows, if the cell in the fifth column contains "NO" using VBA. I can do that by using filters and then use a macro to delete the hidden rows, but I want to find a way to do it in VBAs without using the filters. I want to learn it better and also keep the file for future use.

I have tried to use some scripts I found on stack, but they do not work. Most of them are for integers and not for strings. I have tried this one but it does not work:

```
Sub Delete_Rows_With_Specific_String_In_Cell()
  Dim myRow As Long
  Dim myCounter As Long
  myRow = 390 
  For myCounter = myRow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(myCounter, 5).Value = "NO" Then
        Rows(myCounter).Delete
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

I tried putting a second For for the column but it did not work either. I would like to find a solution on what I have already written. I might be able to find other scripts on the internet, but I want to make it work based on this code.

Comment: Is the sheet your trying to delete rows from active when you run the script?

As you only use **Cells** and **Rows** the code only looks at the currently active sheet.  Try to be explicit about which sheet you want the macro to work on by adding, for example, **ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(myCounter).Delete**

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I have only one sheet in the workbook. So it should work.

Comment: In that case - do all cases say "NO" rather than "no", "No", "nO" or " NO "?  Try using **If UCase(Cells(myCounter, 5).Value) = "NO" Then**  or **If Trim(UCase(Cells(myCounter, 5).Value)) = "NO" Then**

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I do not have a problem with the upper or lower case. I put the link you suggested and still it doesn't work. I made a module and run it but nothing changes. The "NO" is in the fifth column. I presume that the problem is in the syntax of  this:
If Cells(myCounter, 5).Value = "NO" Then

5 is the fifth column.

Comment: I don't know what else to suggest then - if the file only contains a single sheet, and the cells contain the values 'NO' then your original code works fine.

The fifth column is column E?  You haven't got a hidden column somewhere making the fifth visible column something else?

The cells do contain the value 'NO' and not some weird formatting that makes TRUE / FALSE show as YES / NO?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I have tried to change the code. I tried again to check my first version and it worked. I haven't changed anything as far as concerned the original code, filename or anything else. Maybe it was a bug. Sometimes, I was getting an error too. I appreciate what you did. Thankfully my original code was fine. I will come back with more questions on VBA. It is really interesting.

Comment: Interesting - and frustrating at times. I know I've had the same problems as you before - apparently perfect code not doing what it's meant to do. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to delete rows, which may be a little quicker (I haven't tested so don't quote me on that) - figure out which rows need deleting first, union the ranges and delete them all in one go.

```
Sub Delete_Rows_With_Specific_String_In_Cell()

    Dim myRow As Long
    Dim myCounter As Long
    Dim rngDeletion As Range
    myRow = 390

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For myCounter = 1 To myRow
            If .Cells(myCounter, 5).Value = "NO" Then
                If rngDeletion Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngDeletion = .Rows(myCounter)
                Else
                    Set rngDeletion = Union(rngDeletion, .Rows(myCounter))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

    rngDeletion.Delete

End Sub
```

**Note**:  I've used the *With* keyword in the code to ensure I'm referencing the correct sheet all the time.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx for an explanation of *With... End With*.

Answer (score 0):

http://analysistabs.com/vba/delete-row-if-cell-contains-string-excel-macro-example-code/

This solution works

Perhaps you're not inserting as a module?

Comment: It does not. I have added it as a module. The code in the link you sent is wrong. In the "If" function it is "Cells() = "NO"" but it should be "Cells().Value = "NO"".

Comment: **Cells()** and **Cells().Value** will return the same.
Try this test:  **Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value** will return TRUE.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I get an error when I do not put the Cells().Value.

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/20Hg/Book3.xlsm Here is a workbook with your exact code (row is 10 not 390). It works as expected.